# Как правильно использовать api Temp-mail

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие значения куда надо вбивать что бы использовать данный код.
Я уже целый день мучаюсь с этими **public** **static**.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Temp_Mail
{
internal sealed class RGenerator
{
const int BufferSize = 1024;
byte[] RandomBuffer;
int BufferOffset;
static System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng;
static RGenerator()
{
rng = new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
}
public RGenerator()
{
RandomBuffer = new byte[BufferSize];
BufferOffset = RandomBuffer.Length;
}
private byte Next()
{
if (BufferOffset >= RandomBuffer.Length)
{
rng.GetBytes(RandomBuffer);
BufferOffset = 0;
}
return RandomBuffer[BufferOffset++];
}
public int Next(int minValue, int maxValue)
{
int range = maxValue - minValue;
return minValue + Next() % range;
}

const int MinStringLength = 6;
const int MaxStringLength = 10;
public string NextString()
{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int count = Next(MinStringLength, MaxStringLength);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
sb.Append((char)Next('a', 'z'));
return sb.ToString();
}
}
internal static class HTTPWrapper
{
static DateTime unix = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

static XDocument Get(string url)
{
try
{
var req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
req.UserAgent = "CSWrap";
using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
using (var s = resp.GetResponseStream())
return XDocument.Load(s);
}
catch (WebException e)
{
if ((e.Status & WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
return null;
throw;
}
catch { throw; }
}
public static string[] GetDomains()
{
var xml = Get("http://api.temp-mail.ru/request/domains/format/xml/");
return xml.Root.Elements().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
}
public static Letter[] GetLetters(string hash, string lastId = null)
{
var t = Get(string.Format("http://api.temp-mail.ru/request/mail/id/{0}/format/xml/", hash));
if (t == null)
return new Letter[0];

//Жалко, что нельзя просто запросить новые сообщения без кучи старых, 
//А новые сообщения оказываются в самом конце этой кучи =(
var arr = t.Root.Elements().Reverse().ToArray();
var result = new List<Letter>(arr.Length);
foreach (var x in arr)
{
string mailId = x.Element("mail_id").Value;
if (lastId == mailId)
break;
result.Add(new Letter
{
MailId = mailId,
MailAddressId = x.Element("mail_address_id").Value,
MailFrom = x.Element("mail_from").Value,
MailSubject = x.Element("mail_subject").Value,
MailPreview = x.Element("mail_preview").Value,
MailTextOnly = x.Element("mail_text_only").Value,
MailText = x.Element("mail_text").Value,
MailHtml = x.Element("mail_html").Value,
MailTimestamp = unix + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double.Parse(x.Element("mail_timestamp").Value))
});
};
return result.ToArray();
}
}
/// <summary>
/// Сообщение
/// </summary>
public struct Letter
{
/// <summary>
/// Уникальный идентификатор письма, присвоенный системой
/// </summary>
public string MailId;
/// <summary>
/// Md5 хеш почтового адреса
/// </summary>
public string MailAddressId;
/// <summary>
/// Отправитель
/// </summary>
public string MailFrom;
/// <summary>
/// Тема
/// </summary>
public string MailSubject;
/// <summary>
/// Предпросмотр сообщения
/// </summary>
public string MailPreview;
/// <summary>
/// Cообщение в текстовом или в html формате (основной)
/// </summary>
public string MailTextOnly;
/// <summary>
/// Cообщение только в текстовом формате
/// </summary>
public string MailText;
/// <summary>
/// Cообщение только в html формате
/// </summary>
public string MailHtml;
/// <summary>
/// Время
/// </summary>
public DateTime MailTimestamp;
}
/// <summary>
/// API для работы с temp-mail.ru
/// </summary>
public sealed class TempMail
{
RGenerator gen;
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

string lastMailId;
/// <summary>
/// Доступные домены
/// </summary>
public string[] Domains { get; private set; }
/// <summary>
/// Хэш используемого ящика
/// </summary>
public byte[] MailHash { get; private set; }
/// <summary>
/// Хэш используемого ящика
/// </summary>
public string MailHashString { get; private set; }
/// <summary>
/// Имя используемого ящика
/// </summary>
public string Mail { get; private set; }
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public TempMail()
{
gen = new RGenerator();
}

/// <summary>
/// Получает список доступных доменов (@domain)
/// </summary>
public void GetDomains()
{
Domains = HTTPWrapper.GetDomains();
}

/// <summary>
/// Random name(6-10 length string)@Random domain
/// </summary>
public void GetNewMail() { GetNewMail(gen.NextString()); }
/// <summary>
/// mailName@Random domain
/// </summary>
/// <param name="mailName"></param>
public void GetNewMail(string mailName)
{
var domain = Domains[gen.Next(0, Domains.Length - 1)];
Mail = mailName + domain;
MailHash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Mail));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(MailHash.Length * 2);
for (int i = 0; i < MailHash.Length; i++)
sb.Append(MailHash[i].ToString("X2"));
MailHashString = sb.ToString();
}
/// <summary>
/// Получает сообщения с почты
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Пустой массив, если нету сообщений</returns>
public Letter[] GetLetters()
{
var result = HTTPWrapper.GetLetters(MailHashString);
if (result.Length > 0)
lastMailId = result[0].MailId;
return result;
}
/// <summary>
/// Возвращает только новые сообщения
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Пустой массив, если нету новых сообщений</returns>
public Letter[] GetNewLetters()
{
var result = HTTPWrapper.GetLetters(MailHashString, lastMailId);
if (result.Length > 0)
lastMailId = result[0].MailId;
return result;
}
}
}
```

И вроде бы есть комменты но я не могу понять что куда вписывать.
В силу отсутствие знаний.

1. Как посмотреть какие домены есть
2. Как генерировать случайный домен
3. как письма читать и т.д

Вообще нету никаких манов

Comment: Не понимаю в чем проблема. По моему методы названы по смыслу=> имея минимальные знания английского можно понять что нужно вызывать, что бы получить желаемое.

Comment: я и написал, что весь день мучаюсь что не получается разобраться, и так .же плохие знания с# даже правильней будет сказать их вообще нету

Comment: @iluxa1810 я смотрю вы спец в этом деле, так подскажите пожалуйста как вызывать.